# d3.js, grouped bar chart with two Y axes, series related to Y1 or Y2

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

As the starting line I took this code: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/882152 I am trying to create a grouped bar chart that (for example) will have three series, and each of them will have 6 samples. I want each of the series to be relative to its own Y axis (primary or secondary) based on the information passed from the back-end. For example if one of the series has the `AxisType = "1"` then it will be related to the Left Y Axis, else if `AxisType = "2"` then it will be related to the Right Y Axis. I tried to achieve the result I want by myself however I am stuck at the part of the script where it creates the rectangles.
Looking at the result below, how can I achieve the last of the series (the green bars) be related to the second Y axis, not the first one?

```js
var n = 6,  // number of samples
 m = 3; // number of series

var dataset = {
  GraphType: 0,
  Data: []
 };

 dataset.Data.push(
  {
   Axes: [],
   AxisType: "1",
   SeriesData: [{ state: 'CA', age: 2704659 },
    { state: 'TX', age: 2027307 },
    { state: 'NY', age: 1208495 },
    { state: 'FL', age: 1140516 },
    { state: 'IL', age: 894368 },
    { state: 'PA', age: 737462 }],
   GraphType: 0,
   SeriesName: "Under 5 Years"
  },
  {
   Axes: [],
   AxisType: "1",
   SeriesData: [{ state: 'CA', age: 4499890 },
    { state: 'TX', age: 3277946 },
    { state: 'NY', age: 2141490 },
    { state: 'FL', age: 1938695 },
    { state: 'IL', age: 1558919 },
    { state: 'PA', age: 1345341 }],
   GraphType: 0,
   SeriesName: "5 to 13 Years"
  },
  {
   Axes: [],
   AxisType: "2",
   SeriesData: [{ state: 'CA', age: 2159981 },
    { state: 'TX', age: 1420518 },
    { state: 'NY', age: 1058031 },
    { state: 'FL', age: 925060 },
    { state: 'IL', age: 725973 },
    { state: 'PA', age: 1679201}],
   GraphType: 0,
   SeriesName: "14 to 17 Years"
  }
 );

var margin = { top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 80 },
 width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([0, 4499890]) // the biggest number for Primary Axis
 .range([height, 0]);
 
var y2 = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([0, 1679201]) // the biggest number for Secondary Axis
 .range([height, 0]);

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal();
x0.domain(dataset.Data[0].SeriesData.map(function (d) { return d.state; }));
x0.rangeBands([0, width], .2);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
 .domain(d3.range(m))
 .rangeBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);

// colors
var z = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(x0)
 .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(y)
 .orient("left");

var ySecAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(y2)
 .orient("right");

// Append svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("svg:g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Append y axis
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y axis")
 .call(yAxis);

// Append secondary y axis
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y2 axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + " ,0)")
 .call(ySecAxis);

// Append x axis
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
 .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g").selectAll("g")
 .data(dataset.Data)
 .enter().append("g")
 .style("fill", function (d, i) { return z(i); })
 .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(" + x1(i) + ",0)"; })
 .selectAll("rect")
 .data(function(d) { return d.SeriesData; })
 .enter().append("rect")
 .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
 .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.age); })
 .attr("x", function (d) { return x0(d.state); })
 .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.age); });
```

```css
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this:
Must not forget that the anonymous functions can also have three parameters:

```
function (d, i, j) { .... }
```

where the `d` is the data `i` is the inside iterator and `j` is the outside iterator. The solutions looks like the example below:

```js
var n = 6,  // number of samples
 m = 3; // number of series

var dataset = {
  GraphType: 0,
  Data: []
 };

 dataset.Data.push(
  {
   Axes: [],
   AxisType: "1",
   SeriesData: [{ state: 'CA', age: 2704659 },
    { state: 'TX', age: 2027307 },
    { state: 'NY', age: 1208495 },
    { state: 'FL', age: 1140516 },
    { state: 'IL', age: 894368 },
    { state: 'PA', age: 737462 }],
   GraphType: 0,
   SeriesName: "Under 5 Years"
  },
  {
   Axes: [],
   AxisType: "1",
   SeriesData: [{ state: 'CA', age: 4499890 },
    { state: 'TX', age: 3277946 },
    { state: 'NY', age: 2141490 },
    { state: 'FL', age: 1938695 },
    { state: 'IL', age: 1558919 },
    { state: 'PA', age: 1345341 }],
   GraphType: 0,
   SeriesName: "5 to 13 Years"
  },
  {
   Axes: [],
   AxisType: "2",
   SeriesData: [{ state: 'CA', age: 2159981 },
    { state: 'TX', age: 1420518 },
    { state: 'NY', age: 1058031 },
    { state: 'FL', age: 925060 },
    { state: 'IL', age: 725973 },
    { state: 'PA', age: 1679201}],
   GraphType: 0,
   SeriesName: "14 to 17 Years"
  }
 );

var margin = { top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 80 },
 width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([0, 4499890]) // the biggest number for Primary Axis
 .range([height, 0]);
 
var y2 = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([0, 1679201]) // the biggest number for Secondary Axis
 .range([height, 0]);

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal();
x0.domain(dataset.Data[0].SeriesData.map(function (d) { return d.state; }));
x0.rangeBands([0, width], .2);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
 .domain(d3.range(m))
 .rangeBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);

// colors
var z = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(x0)
 .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(y)
 .orient("left");

var ySecAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(y2)
 .orient("right");

// Append svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
 .append("svg:g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Append y axis
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y axis")
 .call(yAxis);

// Append secondary y axis
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "y2 axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + " ,0)")
 .call(ySecAxis);

// Append x axis
svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "x axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
 .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g").selectAll("g")
    .data(dataset.Data)
    .enter().append("g")
    .style("fill", function (d, i) { return z(i); })
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(" + x1(i) + ",0)"; })
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function (d) { return d.SeriesData; })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", function (d, i, j) {  // <----- the change is from here
     if (dataset.Data[j].AxisType === "1")
      return height - y(d.age);
     return height - y2(d.age);
    })
    .attr("x", function (d) { return x0(d.state); })
    .attr("y", function (d, i, j) {
     if (dataset.Data[j].AxisType === "1")
      return y(d.age);
     return y2(d.age);
    });                                    // <------ to here
```

```css
.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```